# How to spy a predefined object with sinon.js

Tags: javascript, testing, sinon, spy

I'm trying to spy window.document with sinon.js. What I do is this:

```
var document = {
    getElementById = function() {}
}

sinon.spy(document, "getElementById").withArgs("foo").returnValues = ["bar"];
```

What I expect from this call is this:
When document.getElementById is called with the argument "foo" the function must return "bar". What's my error?

If I define getElementById by myself like this I get the expected result:

```
document.getElementById = function(param) {
    if (param === "foo") return "bar";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only record calls on function and check that tey was called,  but never change the behavior of the function. From the doc for `withArgs`:

> Creates a spy that only records calls when the received arguments
>   matche those passed to withArgs

Whar you are looking for is a `sinon.stub`:

```
sinon.stub(document, 'getElementById').withArgs('foo').returns(['bar'])
```

Comment: @Aykut Yaman: what you are doing here `document.getElementById = function(param) {
    if (param === "foo") return "bar";}` is replacing the original `getElementById` function permanently. The same thing which is done by `stub`. The only difference being in case of stubs, you have the option to `restore` he original function.